# Android Studio files java

Tags: android, android-studio

Why my files are java files instead as java classes in Android Studio? How it fix ?! Icons in file are red. but before wass blue icon as class.

Comment: because they're not indexed. fix your error, clean and rebuild!

Comment: Have you tried syncing project with gradle files?

Comment: Gradle sync maybe? Or a clean + rebuild? Or a just start a new blank project and copy your files into the new project?

Comment: the reason was file problematic file name_file.iml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason was file problematic file name_file.iml

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can you explain in detail what was the problem and what did you do with the *.iml file in order to resolve this?